Not secure error after implementing SSL certificate in apache and nodejs
My project architecture is as below.
There is two server - web server(Linux) and app server(Ubuntu). My react frontend and nodejs backend are deployed on appserver. And apache(httpd) is installed at webserver. Webserver IP is mapped with the domain and apache is configured as reverseproxy. So whenever anyone hits the domain then the request goes to the appserver via webserver and front end gets opened and nodejs app gets connect to the frontend. But after implementing SSL certificate at the apache the nodejs app was not getting connected. So I added the certificate in nodejs code also and now it is being connected but it shows 'not secure' and under security tab it show main origin of non-secure as ip_of_appserver:8000 and at 8000 port nodejs is running and at 3000 port react app is running. My SSL certificate(1 and 2) is valid for webserver and appserver both as it is for *.domain.com.
I tried setting regitry.
My node version is 16
and SSL version is 3
and TLS protocol is TLS 1.3.
My httpd.conf config file
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName domain.co.in
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/main_corpo.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/corpo_uat.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/chain_corpo.crt
 
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCompression off
SSLSessionTickets off
 
# Security headers
Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
 
ProxyPass "/" "http://ip:3000/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://ip:3000/"
  
</VirtualHost>

I want resolution for not secure error in the web browser.`

Who knows what domain name the certificate you provide is valid for. The name hints that it's not valid for "localhost".
But as you access the site through this name, and the message says "the site is missing a valid, trusted certificate" (implying: for this host name) that's most likely the reason. Or at least the first issue in a chain of issues: I can't guarantee that everything will be fine when you use the proper domain name...

Is there any way to access both fe and be without adding ssl certificate in the nodejs code, in the current architecture.

If you fix the host name issue (e.g. use a valid certificate for the host name), chances are that this additional question is not an issue any more.
